# Smart hub 2 setup

Tags: raspbian-stretch, internet

How do you configure a Raspberry Pi 3 WiFi to access the internet through a BT Smart Hub 2?

Out of the box access to WiFi is reasonable simply but the final connection to the web is proving illusive.

Simple ping test returning “Temporary failure in name resolution” suggesting DHCP issue but as far as I can tell the Smart Hub has assigned a static address.

route -n shows two wlan0 entries

```
1- destination: 0.0.0.0 gateway 192.x.x.254 Genmask 0.0.0.0
2- destination 192.x.x.0 gateway 0.0.0.0 genmask 255.255.255.0
```

Some similar how to guides for various common hardware would be exceptionally useful for frustrated parents and children who don’t have time to study network configuration whilst simultaneously cooking Christmas dinner and preventing children from knocking lumps out of each other :-)

Comment: See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow Milliways suggestion in the comment link above.
Then be patient and wait for a while.

Ideally rebooting the Pi would pick up the network change, but for some reason this takes a while to take affect at either the router of the Pi.

I followed the link, rebooted, same disappointing result.
Turned everything back on the next day and it was working...!

Seem to remember the same sequence of events last time.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.